# Calling function in chrome console doesn't appear to work

Tags: javascript

So on a friend's website, I was testing a function.
I tried "setTokens(10);" which should apparently set the token amount to 10, and it does, but once the page is refreshed, the token amount is then reset back to it's original amount. I've tested other functions of this nature in the console as well and everything is then reset after a refresh. Is there a certain reason why this happening and/or a way to actually make the function work properly? Thanks!

PS: I'm not very experienced with web development so sorry if this problem has a really easy solution.

This is the function which set's the tokens.

```
function setTokens(value){try{$("#userTokens").text(value.toFixed(2));}catch(e){$("#userTokens").text(value);}}
```

In the console, I use the following:

```
setTokens(10);
```

Comment: please provide some code.

Comment: If the value only exists in JavaScript variables or current `document`, it's not supposed to out-live a refresh. All elements and JavaScript variables will be deleted when you unload/leave the current page. You need to use some form of persistence, such as [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), [web storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage), or a [database](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB). Server-side options are also available depending on your choice of tech stack.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I believe that the variable is held in a database as they are saved per profile. I did a bit of digging and found a variable named "data.tokens" but when i attempt to change it, it says "data" was not defined.

Comment: @9AOSMusic The only action that `setTokens()` performs is to display the `value` within an element in the page. Setting the `.text()` of an element alone won't save it for later. If the value is being persisted in other use cases, then there is either another function that needs to be invoked or another action that needs to be taken beyond just calling `setTokens()`.

Comment: Yes, the action that is additionally called that i found was setting data.tokens to a new value, but unfortunately, when i try to also perform that, it says "data" is not defined. I searched for it and could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

You could set and retrieve the value in local storage. JS values are not president. They will reset when the browser is refreshed.

Just to help out. This is not really a bad question for someone who is new.

[localstorage api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)